# I thought my question was a punctuation question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

If I thought my question was a punctuation question (which would be on topic) and all the experts here thought it was a typography or style question (which is understandably off topic) how is it justifiable to close my question based on my incomplete knowledge that I could only gain by asking the question?

See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343510/how-to-show-that-one-long-line-of-poetry-is-only-one-line, I'll wait...

Now, shouldn't the answer be, "this varies by publisher, there's no grammatical way to format poetry, here are some examples... YMMV, etc, etc..."

And if there was an answer, like "use a double virgule", wouldn't that be worth posting?

And, how do you who closed it or answered it starting with "This isn't an English question" know that this question doesn't have an real and definite answer out there?

In closing, benefit of the doubt would be appreciated, I am asking a punctuation question, not a style question.  I want to know because I like posting dumb clerihews on Facebook and quite often it flips on to the next line and my dumb clerihew just became even dumber.  I don't like having to take 10 minutes to defend an indefensible question, but will do so when I think an injustice has occurred.

Thanks for reading and not reversing the charges...

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question: it's about conventional representation of the written dialect, the same semiotic category which legitimates questions about other sorts of pointing.

Comment: @StoneyB Me, too. Which apparently tipped the balance. And I love it when you say *semiotic*.

Comment: Punctuation *is* a matter of style. It's not a matter of grammar. Just remember that around here dismissive contempt trumps justice and the bestowal of benefits of doubts.

Comment: Questions like this which have nothing specific to English should really be asked at [writers.se].

Comment: +1 here for expanding my vocabulary with "clerihew". Oh, and for an articulate yet impassioned plea :-)

Comment: I think that questions about typographical and punctuation style are on topic in any case. But I take a broad view of what "usage" comprehends.

Comment: @deadrat _Semiotic_ ain't nothin. Yesterday in Meta he wrote _orts._